# C# events not firing for new objects

Tags: c#, events

I have an object that parses a lot of realtime data and then fires an event when there is a change in the data. Sometimes, the realtime data can fall out of sync, and when this is detected, it creates a new instance of the object to sync everything back up.

I run a monitor thread that ensures updates are coming through. It looks like this:

```
private async Task DesyncMonitorThread()
{
    while (true)
    {
        if ((DateTime.Now - _lastOrderBookChange) > TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("No order book activity in 30 seconds. Dispatching desync handler.");
            _lastOrderBookChange = DateTime.Now;
            OnDesyncDetected(this, new EventArgs());
        }
        await Task.Delay(1000);
    }
}
```

And the OnDesyncDetected method:

```
private void OnDesyncDetected(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Unsubscribe
    Console.WriteLine("Desync detected. Resyncing order book and prediction engine.");
    if (_book != null)
    {
        _book.OrderBookChanged -= OnBookChange;
        _book.DesyncDetected -= OnDesyncDetected;
    }

    if (_predictor != null)
        _predictor.PredictionChanged -= OnNewPrediction;

    _book = new RealtimeOrderBook(_productId);
    _predictor = new MarketPredictor(_book, Settings.PredictorSettings);

    _book.OrderBookChanged += OnBookChange;
    _book.DesyncDetected += OnDesyncDetected;
    _predictor.PredictionChanged += OnNewPrediction;
}
```

Creating the new object works, and the events that are subscribed to in the new instances of `Book` and `_predictor` fire as intended. However, the event handlers `OnBookChange`, `DesyncDetected`, and `OnNewPrediction` do not.

I want to assume that this has something to do with subscribing to the wrong object, but I can't figure out why. Could it be because this is happening on another thread?

Answer (score -1):

The custom event should be triggered manually, so you can fire OrderBookChanged, DesyncDetected, PredictionChanged events by

```
    _book = new RealtimeOrderBook(_productId);
    _predictor = new MarketPredictor(_book, Settings.PredictorSettings);

    _book.OrderBookChanged += OnBookChange;
    _book.DesyncDetected += OnDesyncDetected;
    _predictor.PredictionChanged += OnNewPrediction;

    _book.OrderBookChanged(_book,new EventArgs());
    _book.DesyncDetected(_book,new EventArgs());
    _predictor.PredictionChanged(_predictor,new EventArgs());
```

or just call the methods directly

```
    _book = new RealtimeOrderBook(_productId);
    _predictor = new MarketPredictor(_book, Settings.PredictorSettings);
    _book.OnBookChange(para);
    _book.OndesyncDetected(para);
    _predictor.OnNewPrediction(para);
```

Comment: I don't see how that would fix the problem. If `_book.OrderBookChanged` is invoked in the `_book` object and the `OnBookChanged` method is subscribed to it, why would I call it manually? The problem here is that when a new object is created to  replace the old `_book` object, the events stop firing.

Comment: Could you show me the code that trigger these events? You just subscribed them in the code you provide, maybe your stop firing problem locate at other place.